# Clamav open source antivirus

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, antivirus

I have been trying to study the source code of clamav open source antivirus as a part of my project. Hence I downloaded the latest stable release `clamav.0.99.2.tar.gz` from the website.

I'm using eclipse neon.2 Release 4.6.2 on Windows 10 64-bit.

I created an existing make file project using the clamav folder extracted, and then converted it into an C/C++ autotools project.

While configuring the project, I get an error "openssl not found", Although I have installed openssl in my cygwin64 terminal and also I run the ecipse from this terminal only.

Is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Did you only install the OpenSSL base package, or the *development* package?

Comment: In the website, [link]https://www.openssl.org/source/ , i downloaded the openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz (SHA256) (PGP sign) (SHA1), i'm sorry..i'm a rookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the terminal in the linux VM, type:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

to install the SSL then from the clamav-0.99.2 directory type:

```
./configure
```

when that completes then type:

```
make
```

This will take a while to complete, then (if you want to actually install the clamav application) type:

```
make install
```

Comment: hey ...yup i installed the openssl development package on my cygwin terminal and now that error is gone and thanks : )

Comment: my project's configuration is successful but when i build it , it shows an error-   /cygdrive/C/Users/Sona/workspace/clamavfinal/Makefile.in] Error 127 clamavfinal  line 589 C/C++ Problem and few warnings - 
Invalid project path: Include path not found (\usr\include). clamavfinal  pathentry Path Entry Problem.

Comment: any help with that ?

Comment: first guess, re-run `setup` and enable the installation of all the header files.

Comment: i managed to remove that error by installing automake 1.14 . But i am stuck with another one which i get during the build.

Comment: configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
make: *** [makefile:613: config.status] Error 1

Comment: open a terminal window (<ctlr-alt-T)  then CD to the top level directory for the application, then type 'make distclean'   The start over with the `./configure` etc.

Comment: Note:  in general, unless something in the environment changes, there is no need to re-run the `./configure` operation.

Comment: Suggest keep re-running `make` and fixing problems until everything cleanly compiles/links